# Stacknavigation inside drawer navigation react native?

Tags: react-native

have to create a drawer and that drawer I want to use on several screens and inside believe a stack but when it comes to running the app I only get the variable when it comes to creating the stack

```
const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    screensStack : createStackNavigator({
      Welcome: Welcome,
      Wellness: Wellness, 
      Market: Market,
    })
  },
{
  drawerWidth: Dimensions.get("window").width * 0.75,
  drawerHeight: Dimensions.get("window").height,
  drawerPosition: "left",
  contentComponet: DrawerContent

}
)

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNav);
```

in the drawer only the word screensStack appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace your code with this

```
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: { screen: Welcome },
    Wellness: { screen: Wellness },
    Market: { screen: Market },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
  }
)

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Drawer',
    headerMode: 'none',
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator)

export default () => <AppContainer />
```

it'll work

Comment: I do not understand very well excuse is that I am new with react native me you could give an example?

Comment: do you need 3 tabs in drawer screen ? @KeinerRdz

Answer (score 0):

The createStackNavigator is located in the drawer. Therefore, when you click a variable in the drawer, you will go to the first screen of the stack navigator.
If you want to make all three variables visible, you need to reposition them.

- createAppContainer

  - createStackNavigator

    - createDrawerNavigator
    - Welcome: Welcome,
    - Wellness: Wellness,
    - Market: Market,